# ST_Union returning Null with Spatialite, even after ST_MakeValid

Tags: sql, spatialite, union

I am attempting to run ST_Union on some features in a GROUP BY Spatialite query, with the aim of counting the number of features, and the total area of those features, which may overlap so should not be summed individually e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT() as tot_count, ST_Area(ST_Union(geom)) AS tot_area
FROM features
```

However, with various methods, ST_Union always returns Null, as does ST_UnaryUnion. I can use ST_Collect fine, and get the total area from that, but I believe this will not account for the possible overlap in the features.

There are initially four invalid geometries in the features, as identified by ST_IsValid. Fixing these with ST_MakeValid appears successful (confirmed by ST_IsValid), but does not fix the issue, nor does ST_Buffer(geom, 0). However, if I specifically exclude those four invalid geometries with a where clause, the Union produces a result. Any ideas on the problem? Are the geometries still invalid, despite running ST_MakeValid, and ST_IsValid confirming this was successful? Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution that seems to work is to union the valid and invalid geometries separately,  make those valid, and then union the result e.g.

```
SELECT ST_Union(ST_MakeValid(geom))
FROM (SELECT ST_IsValid(geom) AS Valid, ST_Union(geom) AS geom
    FROM features
    GROUP BY Valid)
```

Perhaps an inefficient way to do it though?